# build pandas documentation from source using installed pandas rather than an inplace build

Tags: pandas, python-sphinx

My question is: How can I use my up to date pandas installation to build the pandas documentation?

I read the pandas/doc/README.rst, which says to navigate to the `pandas/doc` directory and run `python make.py html`. Unfortunately, this does not work for me as it seems to require having first done an inplace build of pandas. My (windows) computer does not have the necessary prerequisites for doing a development build, and it seems to be an unnecessary burden when I just want to add some notes that improve the documentation.

The background for why I am asking this question is that earlier this week I posted a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773073) about pandas hdf5 output. In [discussing the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773073/save-pandas-dataframe-using-h5py-for-interoperabilty-with-other-hdf5-readers/30773118#comment49633465_30787168) with Jeff, he encouraged me to add some commentary to the documentation. So I forked the pandas repository and began to think about how I would add to the documentation. I am not interested in setting up a development build of the complete pandas installation. I would like to be able to modify the documentation, build it, and see my changes before submitting a pull request. Is there a reasonable way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this be something you post on [`github`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues) rather than SO?

Comment: I am sometimes unsure what to post where. I thought this was a general pandas question about how to contribute to pandas documentation so it should go on SO. Now that I have seen this is a bug (or undocumented feature--see my comment below), I made an [issue on github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10340).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/contributing.html) are the pandas contributing guidelines & howto's.

Comment: I had seen that. I discovered the problem I have is that the ``make.py`` script has the statement ``os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = '..'``, which seems to force python to get pandas from the source tree. I commented out that line and now the error I was getting with ``python make.py html`` seems to have gone away and the html documentation is generated. I will forge ahead with adding my 2 cents to the documentation.