# how i can add this data frame into data set in HDF5 file?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, hdf5

I need to move this data frame to hdf5 file. when i create data set `hf.create_dataset('dataset_1', data=df)` the error is `TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent`

```
PATH = r"/...." # your Path
extension = 'csv'
os.chdir(PATH)
csv_list = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))
print(csv_list)

# creates new df
df = pd.DataFrame()

for csv in csv_list:
    temp = pd.read_csv(csv)
    df = pd.concat([df, temp], ignore_index=True)
    
df.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30773073/14108734) it may solve your problem.